# WCF Two way mutual authentication

Tags: wcf, service

How to implement Two way mutual broker Authentication at transport level? I need a suitable example with certificates created by makecert.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650785.aspx). It should guide you step by step. The only thing I don't like in this article is that it uses Web Site. Web site is probably the worst choice for hosting WCF service in IIS. I would choose WCF Service application. There are additional resources at the end which will point you to articles about creating and installing temporary certificates.